# Android: Save checkboxes in SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite

I have to create one list view with checkboxes and then save all selected checkboxes in the table in sqlite. and then show the database table in next activity.

Comment: What things have you tried so far?

Comment: You have to create a table that has columns to store the value for each checkbox.

Comment: Do you need to use a database? Instead, you could use [preferences](http://www.kaloer.com/android-preferences), which would store the checkboxes in [shared preferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). It also will provide the support needed for making the view, so you don't have to implement your own `ListView`.

Comment: Is this checkbox selected data persistent? If not then pass this checked data as bundle to next activity..So no need to create database...

Comment: Thanks for telling us. Let us know if you have a question.

Answer (score 0):

For each checkbox you put in the listview you can add and onClickListener to the checkbox. In the onClickListener you make your call to the sqlite database and set a column in a row to true to show that it's been checked.

Comment: Sorry I can't help write an entire Android app for you. And doesn't that defeat the purpose of a company interviewing you? They want to know about your skills, not mine.